# When generating contract metadata with `sp.init_metadata` do you include or exclude on-chain views in the `views` array in the metadata?

Tags: smartpy, tzip16, on-chain-views, off-chain-views, metadata

When performing

```
self.init_metadata("metadata", some_metadata)
```

on contract metadata inside smartpy, should the list of views inside the TZIP-16 metadata only contain off-chain views, or must on-chain views also be included in this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the compiler interprets `on-chain` views the same way as `off-chain` views when it comes to metadata (not included in the contract code).

If the `off-chain` view has the same logic as the `on-chain` view, you can remove the `off-chain` entirely and just use the `on-chain` view.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include the on-chain views there. Here, an image from the [docs](https://smartpy.io/docs/guides/metadata/contract_metadata/):

[image: on-chain views]